# Using SpecFlow with Windows Store / UWP apps and CodedUI

Tags: win-universal-app, coded-ui-tests, specflow, windows-store

It seems that UWP and Store apps are not fully supported by SpecFlow as of now.

Are there any workarounds for using SpecFlow with Windows Store apps / UWP apps and more specifically with Coded UI projects (Windows Store, not regular ones)?

If not, are there any alternatives to it considering BDD and writing executable acceptance tests for Windows Store / UWP platforms?

Comment: Did you by any chance solve this? Would like some answers myself.